# RadMonthYearPicker POST Data Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have an ASP form that with a telertik RadMonthYearPicker on it. When I POST the page the control data is not in the format I need it in, and has extra fields I don't want. Is there a way to control the field data format and remove the extra fields. The only form field I want is **x_exp_date**.

**aspx markup**

```
...
<td>
    <telerik:RadMonthYearPicker ClientIDMode="Static" ID="x_exp_date" name="x_exp_date" runat="server" 
        DateInput-DisplayDateFormat="MM/yyyy" 
        DateInput-DateFormat="MM/yyyy" 
        MinDate="<%#DateTime.Now%>">
    </telerik:RadMonthYearPicker>
</td>
...
```

This is the form post data.

```
&x_exp_date_AD=%5B%5B1980%2C1%2C1%5D%2C%5B2099%2C12%2C31%5D%2C%5B2014%2C1%2C7%5D%5D
&x_exp_date=2015-01-07 <-- this is the only field I need/want but it must be formatted MM/yyyy
&x_exp_date%24dateInput=01%2F2015
&x_exp_date_dateInput_ClientState=%7B%22enabled%22%3Atrue%2C%22emptyMessage%22%3A%22%22%2C%22validationText%22%3A%222015-01-07-00-00-00%22%2C%22valueAsString%22%3A%222015-01-07-00-00-00%22%2C%22minDateStr%22%3A%221980-01-01-00-00-00%22%2C%22maxDateStr%22%3A%222099-12-31-00-00-00%22%2C%22lastSetTextBoxValue%22%3A%2201%2F2015%22%7D
&x_exp_date_ClientState=
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any property or method on the Telerik controls that controlled what was included in the POST data so I used JavaScript and some jQuery to remove the unwanted fields and format the data in the others. Setting the disabled attribute of the element to "disabled" removes the field from the POST data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#form1').submit(function () {
            modifyPostData();
            return true;
        });
    });
    function modifyPostData() {
        $('input[name="x_exp_date_ClientState"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('input[name="x_exp_date_AD"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('input[name="x_exp_date_dateInput_ClientState"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('input[name="x_exp_date\\$dateInput"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
</script>
```